# How to get base url along with path in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-router

My current url is http://localhost:4200/myApp/dashboard.

I want to print base url i.e http://localhost:4200/myApp using angular 5 features.

I am using this code:

```
constructor(private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
}

const appPath = (this.platformLocation as any).location.origin
```

however it returns only domain name  http://localhost:4200

Comment: have you tried: window.location.href

Comment: yes, it too returns root domain

Comment: have you tried this.router.url;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added base_href value in app module providers

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "http://localhost:4500/MyApp" }
]
```

and in the code

```
import { LocationStrategy, Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {}
const appPath = location.origin + this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref();
```

Fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-rqcji3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: this part I was looking for `this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref()`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location):

import:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```

Inject:

```
constructor(@Inject(Location) private readonly location: Location) {}
```

Use:

```
const pathAfterDomainName = this.location.path();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject `Router` from `@angular/router` and use `this.router.url`

The baseHref should be available using `this.router.location._baseHref`

Answer (score 0):

Some other solution:

```js
import { DOCUMENT, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: any,
    private readonly locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {}

  // for localhost: http://localhost:4200/someBaseHref
  getUrl(): string {
    return `${this.document.location.origin}/${this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref()}`
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'path-location',
  providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}],
  template: `
    <h1>PathLocationStrategy</h1>
    Current URL is: <code>{{myLocation.path()}}</code><br>
    BaseHref is: <code>{{myLocation.getBaseHref()}}</code><br>
  `
})
export class PathLocationComponent {

  public myLocation: LocationStrategy;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

    /** Define i18n idioma do sistema */
    this.myLocation= this.injector.get(LocationStrategy);

    console.log('BaseHref: ' + this.myLocation.getBaseHref());
    console.log('Path: ' + this.myLocation.path());
  }
}
```

**Based on:** https://angular.io/api/common/Location#example

**And:** https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy